# Unity Converting Microphone input into Hertz

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity app that has some Microphone controls. At one point, I have to convert the Microphone input into Hertz (Hz) values and show them to the user. Now, I did some research and I made the following script for this purpose:

```
int amountSamples = 1024;

 void Start ()
        {
            _fSample = AudioSettings.outputSampleRate;
        }

 void Update() {
            
            if (focused && Initialized) {
                if (Microphone.IsRecording(selectedDevice) && recording) {
                    
                        spectrumData = GetSpectrumAnalysis();
                        
                        if (spectrumCurve.keys.Length <= spectrumData.Length) {
                           
                            float keyTimeValue = 0;
                            float currentHighestKeyTime = 0;

                            //create a curvefield if none exists
                            spectrumCurve = new AnimationCurve();

                            for (int t = 0; t < spectrumData.Length; t++) {
                                spectrumCurve.AddKey(1 / spectrumData.Length + t, spectrumData[t]);
                                spectrumCurve.MoveKey(1 / spectrumData.Length + t, new Keyframe(1 / spectrumData.Length + t, keyTimeValue = spectrumData[t])); //update keyframe value
                                if (keyTimeValue > currentHighestKeyTime) {
                                    currentHighestKeyTime = keyTimeValue;
                                }
                            }

                            HighestKeyTimeValue = currentHighestKeyTime;
                            float freqN = HighestKeyTimeValue;
                            float f = freqN * (_fSample / 2) / amountSamples;
                            Debug.Log(f); //hz

                        }
                    }
                }
                audioSource.volume = 1;
            }
```

And the GetSpectrumAnalysis()

```
 public float[] GetSpectrumAnalysis ()
        {
            float[] dataSpectrum = new float[amountSamples];
            audioSource.GetSpectrumData (dataSpectrum, 0, FFTWindow.BlackmanHarris); 
            for (int i = 0; i <= dataSpectrum.Length - 1; i++)
            {

                dataSpectrum[i] = Mathf.Abs (dataSpectrum[i] * sensitivity);

            }
            return dataSpectrum;

        }
```

Now, with this code, the Hz value should be calculated in *float f*, it does work but the Hz values aren't too accurate, for example, I'm getting 400-500 Hz where I should get around 880 Hz. Similarly I'm getting 130 Hz instead of 220 Hz, etc.. So, I have 2 issues: I'm getting less Hz then I should and the Hz value is jumping too much and too fast so it's not consistent even if the sound playing is constant. Any idea how to improve this code? Where did I made a mistake?

**EDIT**
Check my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, nevermind, I found the solution, maybe this will help someone stumbling across this thread, change *GetSpectrumAnalysis* method to this:

```
public float test() {
            float Threshold = 0.02f;
            float[] dataSpectrum = new float[amountSamples];
            audioSource.GetSpectrumData(dataSpectrum, 0, FFTWindow.BlackmanHarris); //Rectangular
            float maxV = 0;
            var maxN = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < amountSamples; i++) {
                if (!(dataSpectrum[i] > maxV) || !(dataSpectrum[i] > Threshold)) {
                    continue;
                }

                maxV = dataSpectrum[i];
                maxN = i; // maxN is the index of max
            }

            float freqN = maxN; // pass the index to a float variable
            if (maxN > 0 && maxN < amountSamples - 1) { // interpolate index using neighbours
                var dL = dataSpectrum[maxN - 1] / dataSpectrum[maxN];
                var dR = dataSpectrum[maxN + 1] / dataSpectrum[maxN];
                freqN += 0.5f * (dR * dR - dL * dL);
            }

            return freqN * (_fSample / 2) / amountSamples; // convert index to frequency
        }
```

Then just call this in the update method like this:

```
Text.text = test().ToString("00");
```

For more info check out this thread: [Unity answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/157940/getoutputdata-and-getspectrumdata-they-represent-t.html)